# How to retrieve multiple objects using AJAX in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am preparing an 'admin' notes table in my website. Basically, I want to do two things:

1. Insert a new note into 'notes' table in DB using AJAX.
2. If the the insertion is successful, update the notes table displayed on the page using AJAX.

-

```
$('#form_add_btn').click(function(){

    var form_data = {
        note: $('#note_text').val(),
        type: $('#form_type_select').val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/add_note",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $('#note_msg').html(msg); 
        }
    });

return false;
});
```

At the moment controller method add_note() adds the note via model and returns true or false, which is loaded into view and returned.

```
public function add_note() {
    $note = $this->input->post('note');
    $type = $this->input->post('type');

    $data['is_success'] = $this->model_admin->add_note($note, $type);
    $this->load->view('admin/add_note', $data);
}
```

I would like to do another AJAX request if $data['is_success'] is true :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/get_notes_table",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(table) 
        {
            $('#wrap').html(table);
        }
});
```

How can I acomplish this ? I tried placing the second request inside and after the first,  but I still need to known if the insertion was successful.

I'm just beginning to learn CI and AJAX in jQuery, would really appreciate your help. Thanks !

Comment: try json, then you will not need a second request.

Comment: Not really familiar with JSOn yet, but I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can do this in one ajax call only**, just change the add_note controller function,
and instead of returning the true/false in the view, it should return you the **json**.
This json will contain, either success or false along with the new list of notes. you can parse this json in the success function to show the notes.

```
    public function add_note() {
        $note = $this->input->post('note');
        $type = $this->input->post('type');

        $data['is_success'] = $this->model_admin->add_note($note, $type);
        if($data['is_success']){
          //get the new notes from the db including the new one
          $data['result']     = "success";
          $data['motes'] = notes from DB
        }else{
          $data['result'] = "fail";
        }

        echo json_encode($data);exit;

}
```

Its benefits are, your one ajax call is saved, means the user exp will be better, as he will not have to wait more.